# How can we set consistency level seperatly for read and write in cassandra (cqlsh)

Tags: cassandra, consistency

Can someone help me on how to set consistency level separately for read and write in cassandra (cqlsh) 
and one more question can we set consistency level for a keyspace?
please explain

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set consistency level other then your default consistency level. (which you have defined while building your cluster object).

Here is the example of setting consistency level to your prepared statement.

```
session.prepare(<Query>).setConsistencyLevel(<consistency_level>)
```

If you are using JAVA driver, you can explore the enum class **ConsistencyLevel** defined in the datastax driver library.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.ConsistencyLevel.{consistency_level}
```

This link might help you [dmlConfigConsistency](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html)

Answer (score 1):

For setting this in `cqlsh` you need to issue corresponding [`CONSISTENCY` command](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshConsistency.html) before executing the specific query, like this:

```
CONSISTENCY QUORUM;
INSERT INTO ... ;
```

Setting the consistency level for "class" of queries is impossible in `cqlsh`...

Answer (score 0):

You can set consistency after login CQLSH like below for read and write.
CONSISTENCY ONE/TWO; etc
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshConsistency.html

Also,you can refer below for setting a Consistency Level with Prepared Statements
https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html